# Common path prefix in Play framework 2.2.x scala JSON Reads

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

I would like to only read "value" from the following JSON

```
{
  "field": "feed",
  "value": {
    "item": "post",
    "verb": "add",
    "post_id": 1234568567515,
    "sender_id": 10200718414514
  }
}
```

into this:

```
case class Value (
  item: String,
  verb: String,
  itemId: Long,
  senderId: Long
)
```

The Reads[Value] looks like this:

```
implicit val valueReads: Reads[Value] = (
  (__ \ "item").read[String] and
  (__ \ "verb").read[String] and
  (__ \ "post_id").read[Long] and
  (__ \ "sender_id").read[Long]
) ( Value )
```

How can I specify the common parent node "value" for all the paths in Reads without repeating it all over the place like (__ \ "value" \ "item"), (__ \ "value" \ "verb") etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work:

```
implicit val valuereads = (__ \ "value").read {
  ((__ \ "item").read[String] and
   (__ \ "verb").read[String] and
   (__ \ "post_id").read[Long] and
   (__ \ "sender_id").read[Long] 
   )(Value.apply _)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but if you want skip manually writing `Reads` objects, you can use macros. But for that case you should have parent case class, which will have inside two fields: `field` and `value`.

So it'll be something like:

```
case class Value (
  item: String,
  verb: String,
  itemId: Long,
  senderId: Long
)

case class MyClass(field: String, value: Value)


implicit val myClassReads = Json.reads[MyClass]
implicit val valueReads = Json.reads[Value]
```

So at the end you can get your `value` from the `MyClass` object.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been easy, but the point is I am not interested in "field", I want Value to be the result of parsing the whole JSON. My situation is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122175/scala-play-json-reads) in that the "value" key to me is something that gets in the way and does not carry any useful information, just like "business" key from that question.